Comparative and Superlative Adjectives
Kindly help me find the best answer to the following questions:

Sally is the (clever, cleverer, cleverest) of the twins.
Both cakes are tasty, but this one is the (tastier, tastiest).
There were two bikes for sale. Mrs.Lee bought the (cheaper, cheapest) one.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

We usually use the "comparative" (cleverer) when there are only two items being compared, rather than the superlative (cleverest). Note that the definite article (the) is an optional stylistic choice in example #2, but required in #1 and #3.

Does this answer your question? Comparative vs. Superlative While Comparing Two Items. Also How does "the + comparative adjective" work here? and "The Willis Tower is taller" or "the Willis Tower is the taller", among others.
